# Drawing component diagrams in TinyUML

Tags: uml, components, graphviz, dot

I am working on extending a small application that uses the 'dot' tool to draw UML class and state diagrams, to implement component diagrams (I am running into a lot of problems accommodating the UML 2.x notation for the same).

I intend to display the interfaces that a particular component requires and provides through the use of lollipop notations. Now while trying to do so, I am not able to display the edges between two nodes as a straight line. Even if I am able to display one edge as a straight edge, I am unable to maintain that state for all the edges.

Just wanted to know is there any particular way apart from the usual attributes like weight, len (for neato), k, etc.? (or indeed any other tools that u may suggest ?) Appreciate your help.

Best,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I never used TinyUML, but as you asked for any other tool suggestion let me tell you  that I'm very comfortable using [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) (Open Source).

Comment: TinyUML is actually the intended name of my software (in no way related to any other TinyUML projects that you may find on the web, simply 'coz I havent hosted it yet).

Anyways, any alternatives to the dot graph drawing tool? Its spline curves as edges are driving me crazy and i need to find ways to "draw" a UML 2.x notation for a software component. Badly need edges to be straight, short and customizable to a fair extent. Dot does seem to do a decent job but has let me down big-time as far as component diagrams are concerned...

Thanks for your help!